# Distinguishing between notification received and notification touched

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to perform some action when the user taps on the notification message in the iOS notification centre. 
I know the method `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif` is called when I touch the notification, but it is also called when a notification is just received and not tapped. I want a way to distinguish between two.

I couldn't find any useful solution specific to this anywhere so please help me out. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add this in the application:appdidReceiveLocalNotifcation:notif method

```
UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];

if(state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
    //The app is in the foreground
}
```

Comment: but if I receive notification while I am using the app this action will be executed, without even tapping on the notification. Even if the app is in foreground I don't want to do anything unless the user taps on notification from the notification centre.

Comment: `application:appdidReceiveLocalNotifcation:notif` is going to run when you receive a push notification whether the app is in the foreground or not. If you only want something to happen when the user taps on a push notification try putting `if(state != UIApplicationStateActive` in the method and put whatever you want to happen in the if statement. If that isn't what you want there are different `UIApplicationState` you can check for